# Algebraic logical structure

Tags: lo.logic, universal-algebra, modal-logic, algebraic-systems

Let $M=(W,R)$ be a Kripke frame, $A=(f_1,...,f_m)$ is a tuple of operations $f_i:W^{n_i}\to W$, and $\Phi=(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_m  )$ is a tuple of first-order logic formulas in vocabulary $\sigma=\{=,R, \models\}$ with according semantic ( $=\subseteq W^2, \models \subseteq W\times Prop$ ). Let for any propositional modal formula $\psi$ and any worlds $w_1,...,w_{n_i}$ the following property hold:
$$f_i(w_1,...,w_{n_i})\models \psi \longleftrightarrow \varphi_i(\psi,w_1,...,w_{n_i})$$
Then we call the triple $(M,A,\Phi)$ ALM-algebra. For example, for all $*:W^2\to W$ the triple $(M,*,\varphi_{\oplus})$ is not an ALM-algebra, where $\varphi_{\oplus}(\psi,w_1,w_2)=(w_1 \models \psi )\oplus(w_2 \models \psi)$.

Is there any criterion for $\Phi$ and $A$ that allows us to determine whether a given algebra is a ALM-algebra? For which tuples of formulas does no tuple of operations give an ALM-algebra?
And of course, if something is already known about these structures, then share the links.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of answer you are seeking? Since you defined the ALM-algebras, this clearly provides a criterion. And when you say "a given algebra" what do you mean exactly? The form of ALM algebras is not the form of an algebra in, say, universal algebra. Do you mean which universal algebras can be equiped with the corresponding modal structure so as to be realized as the underlying algebra of operations from an ALM algebra?

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins, I incorrectly expressed myself by saying "given algebra", I mean given triple. The definition does not provide an easy way to identify ALM-algebras.  I'm looking for some equivalent easy-to-check criteria, or some conditions to make the check easier.